# Discussion about Warren-Cowely Parameter

Tags: bond, solutions, entropy

The Warren-Cowely Parameter (WCP) for short range solution order is defined as:
$$\mathrm{WCP}_{ij} = 1 - \frac{Z_{ij}}{x_j \cdot Z_i}$$

where $Z_{ij}$ is the **partial** Coordination Number (CN) of  j atoms around i, $Z_{i}$ is the **total** CN around i, and $ x_{j}$ is the nominal composition of j.

Consider a two component solution of $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$.  If $\mathrm{WCP}>0$, like neighbors are preferred, If $\mathrm{WCP}<0$, unlike neighbors are preferred.

If both of $\mathrm{WCP}_{AA}$ and $\mathrm{WCP}_{BB}$ are positive, which one is preferred?

Comment: Could you clarify what $Z_{ij}$ and $x_j$ are in your equations? Does your definition match the one in this paper: https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/29021/0000051.pdf;sequence=1

Comment: Dear @Tyberius I have updated my question, and added the definitions

Comment: @Tyberius do you not have any idea about this question? I checked the parameter with the definition in the paper you introduced, they are identical

Comment: I do not know for sure. It could be that $WCP_{AB} is what actually matters.$WCP_{AA}$ and $WCP_{BB}$ both positive seems to me like it implies that both components prefer like neighbors. I had hoped clarifying your question and introducing some terminology for people who aren't familiar (like myself) would encourage an answer.